# Mongoose .findByIdAndUpdate() console log the return but can't assign to a property

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, graphql

I wrote this function to update a data in MongoDB:

```
const Sequence = require('../models/sequenceSchema');

module.exports.genNumber = function () {
    let doc = Sequence.findByIdAndUpdate(
        {_id: "5e1f72951c9d440000afce53"},
        {$inc:{sequence_value: 1}},
        {new: true},
        function(err,result){
            if(err) return console.log(err)


            return result.sequence_value;
        }
    )
};
```

In the Mutation resolve I wrote this code:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const functions = require('../modules/functions');

const Mutation = new GraphqlObjectType({
(..)
resolve(parent,args){
                let ticket = new Ticket({
                    name: args.name,
                    number: functions.genNumber(),                        
                    opendate: Date(),
                    product: args.product,
                    priority: args.priority,
                    status: args.status,
                    deadline: calcs.deadline(Date(),args.priority),
                    userid: args.userid
                });
```

My issue is that the function `findByIdAndUpdate()` update the value on MongoDB, but is not assigning to the property `number:`. If I return the `result` in a console log it shows perfectly, I'm not understanding what is happening. I'm using Graphql/Mongoose/MongoDB

Comment: Can you try this :: `module.exports.genNumber = (req, done) => {
    Sequence.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: "5e1f72951c9d440000afce53" }, { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } }, { new: true },
        function (err, result) {
            if (err) { console.log(err), done(err) }; done(null, result.sequence_value)
        }
    )
};`

Comment: @srinivasy it throws an error saying `TypeError: done is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because:

1. The `genNumber` function is not returning anything
2. If the `genNumber` function returns something, it would be a promise and the promise needs to be resolved before being used when creating a Ticket.

This updated code snippet should work:

```
const Sequence = require('../models/sequenceSchema');

module.exports.genNumber = function () {
  // Notice the return statement below
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Sequence.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: "5e1f72951c9d440000afce53" },
      { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } },
      { new: true },
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return reject(err);
        }
        console.log('Result: ', result);
        return resolve(result.sequence_value);
      }
    )
  })
};
```

=

```
const Mutation = new GraphqlObjectType({
  // (..)
  // Notice the resolve method becomes an asynchronous
  resolve: async (parent, args) => {
    // Notice the await on functions.genNumber call
    const number = await functions.genNumber();
    let ticket = new Ticket({
      name: args.name,
      number: number,
      opendate: Date(),
      product: args.product,
      priority: args.priority,
      status: args.status,
      deadline: calcs.deadline(Date(), args.priority),
      userid: args.userid
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: the `await functions.genNumber();` is returning the whole query not the `result.sequence_value`. This is really cracking my head

Comment: Yes, I think I know why that is still happening. You need to promise-ify the `genNumber` method. I updated the code snippet.